# C++: Linked list destructor memory leak?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm going to be upfront and apologize for asking for your help. I really don't deserve it in any way. I also apologize for what I know is my sloppy code. I don't want to be *that* guy, but I'm really stumped as to what I should do.

Here's the story so far:

### list.cpp

```
Node::Node()
{
    next = nullptr;
    book = nullptr;
}

Node::Node(Book* newBook)
{
    next = nullptr;
    book = newBook;
}

Node::~Node()
{
    if (next != nullptr)
    {
        delete book;
    }
}

Node* Node::getNextNode() const
{
    return next;
}

void Node::setNext(Node* newNext)
{
    if (newNext == nullptr)
    {
        next = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        next = newNext;
    }
}

Book* Node::getBook() const
{
    return book;
}

List::List()
{
    first = nullptr;
    last = nullptr;
    numNodes = 0;
}

List::~List()
{
    Node* tempNode = first;
    first = first->getNextNode();

    while (first != nullptr)
    {
        delete tempNode;
        numNodes--;
        tempNode = first;
        first = first->getNextNode();
    }
    last = nullptr;
}

void List::push_front(Node* newNode)
{
    Node* tempNode = first;
    newNode->setNext(tempNode);
    first = newNode;
    if (last == nullptr)
    {
        last = first;
    }
    numNodes++;
}

void List::push_back(Node* newNode)
{
    Node* tempNode = last;
    tempNode->setNext(newNode);
    last = newNode;
    if (first == nullptr)
    {
        first = last;
    }
    numNodes++;
}

Node* List::pop_front()
{
    if (first != nullptr)
    {
        Node* tempNode = first;
        if (tempNode->getNextNode() == nullptr)
        {
            numNodes--;
            return first;
        }
        if (first == last)
        {
            numNodes--;
            first = nullptr;
            return first;
        }
        first = first->getNextNode();
        numNodes--;
        return tempNode;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

Node* List::pop_back()
{
    if (last != nullptr)
    {
        Node* tempNode = first;
        if (first == last)
        {
            numNodes--;
            first = nullptr;
            return first;
        }
        if (tempNode->getNextNode() == nullptr)
        {
            numNodes--;
            return first;
        }
        while (tempNode->getNextNode()->getNextNode() != nullptr)
        {
            tempNode = tempNode->getNextNode();
        }
        last = tempNode;
        last->next = nullptr;
        numNodes--;
        return tempNode;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

Node* List::getFirst() const
{
    return first;
}

Node* List::getLast() const
{
    return last;
}
```

### driver.cpp

```
int main()
{

    // set up cout for displaying prices
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    // create a List object
    List partsList;

    cout << "\nPart I: multiple node test: push_front and pop_front\n";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";
    // build a List using push_front
    partsList.push_front(new Node(new Book("Fun With C++", "I. M. Codemann", 95.00)));
    partsList.push_front(new Node(new Book("Lousy Linked Lists", "B. A. Hacker", 74.90)));
    partsList.push_front(new Node(new Book("Programming Nuts", "R. U. Krazy", 85.25)));
    partsList.push_front(new Node(new Book("Silly Syntax", "Irma Coder", 30.15)));

    cout << "\nThe original nodes in the List:\n";
    printList(partsList);
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";

    // test push_front function
    cout << "\nAdding to the front of the List:\n";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";
    partsList.push_front(new Node(new Book("Python's a Snake", "C. Rules", 65.45)));
    partsList.push_front(new Node(new Book("Programming Fables", "J. Aesop", 73.15)));

    printList(partsList);
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";

    // test pop-front
    cout << "\nRemoving the first node from the list.\n";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";
    Node* item = partsList.pop_front();
    printList(partsList);
    if (item != NULL)
        delete item;

    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";
    cout << "\nPart Two: Push_back and pop_back";

    // test push_back
    partsList.push_back(new Node(new Book("Coding Shortcuts", "B. Lazy", 110.25)));
    partsList.push_back(new Node(new Book("Famous Programmers I Know", "M. T. Set", 126.00)));

    cout << "\nAdding two nodes at the end\n";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";
    printList(partsList);

    // test pop-back
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";
    cout << "\nRemove last node from the list\n";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";
    item = partsList.pop_back();
    printList(partsList);
    if (item != NULL)
        delete item;

    // delete all of the Nodes in the list
    cout << "\nEmpty the list and delete all nodes\n";
    while (partsList.getFirst() != nullptr)
    {
        Node * t = partsList.pop_front();
        delete t;
    }
    printList(partsList);

    // Test Push_front and pop_back - do they handle special case
    cout << "\nTesting special case handling for push_front and pop_back\n";
    partsList.push_front(new Node(new Book("Test Book 1", "nobody", 1.25)));
    Node* t = partsList.pop_back();
    cout << "\nThe Node just removed contains " << t->getBook()->getTitle() << endl;
    delete t;

    // Test push_back and pop_front - do they handle special cases
    cout << "\nTesting special case handling for push_back and pop_front\n";
    partsList.push_back(new Node(new Book("Test Book 2", "nobody", 1.25)));
    t = partsList.pop_front();
    cout << "\nThe Node just removed contains " << t->getBook()->getTitle() << endl;
    delete t;

    // Is the list now empty
    cout << "\nThe list should now be empty...\n";
    printList(partsList);

    cout << "\n-------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "\nEnd of Test";
    cout << "\n-------------------------------------------\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void printList(const List& theList)
{
    if (theList.getFirst() == nullptr) // if the list is empty
        cout << "\nempty list\n";
    else
    {
        Node* t = theList.getFirst();
        while (t != NULL)
        {
            Book* bp = t->getBook();
            cout << bp->getTitle() << ' ';
            cout << bp->getAuthor() << ' ';
            cout << "$" << bp->getPrice() << endl;
            t = t->getNextNode();
        }
    }
}

void printFirstNode(List theList)
{
    Node* t = theList.getFirst();
    Book* bp = t->getBook();
    cout << bp->getTitle() << ' ';
    cout << bp->getAuthor() << ' ';
    cout << "$" << bp->getPrice() << endl;
    t = t->getNextNode();
}
```

Alright, so what I have so far for my linked list seems to run relatively smoothly so far. The program only throws an exception (Unhandled exception at 0x00E5654B in Proj_02.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xDDDDDDF1.) at the homestretch, the last printList function call. I'm not really sure why this exception is being thrown, the list should be completely empty. And so, I must hang my head in shame. What should I do to fix this issue?

Thank you. From the bottom of my heart.

Comment: By the exceptions it looks like you're running in a Windows environment.  What compiler are you using?  Are you using an IDE such as Visual Studio, CodeBlocks or Eclipse?  All of these have integrated debuggers that could break on the offending line of code, and you could figure out what's happening.

Comment: You will get much better answers if you provide a [mcve].

Comment: Honestly, this implementation of a linked list is strange.   Why does the main program know anything about `Node`s?  Shouldn't the `List` class figure out and handle the `Node` objects within itself?  I would expect `partsList.push_front(Book(...whatever...))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thomasz' answer is right so far, just some additional hints:

Wherever you set one of first or last to nullptr, do it for the other one, too:

```cpp
first = last = nullptr;
```

`push_back` won't work, if the list is empty, last is nullptr itself then. Try this instead:

```cpp
if(!last)
{
    first = last = newNode;
}
else
{
    last->setNext(newNode);
    last = newNode;
}
++numNodes;
```

The Node class should be an internal detail of your list class, else you allow to modify the list externally without the List knowing about it! Make Node an inner class, and change the List's public interface such that it handles a Book* wherever you had a Node* before. Create and delete the Nodes within the List's functions then - and do not delete the Book from within the Node's destructor. You can still use the Node class to iterate the List, though, so it would correspond to the ::std::list's iterator.

And you can assign newNext directly: even if it is a null pointer, `next` still will be assigned exactly this, so the check is simply superfluous:

```cpp
void Node::setNext(Node* newNext)
{
    // if (newNext == nullptr)
    //{
    //    next = nullptr;
    //}
    //else
    //{
        next = newNext;
    //}
}
```

May I assume that you wrote the list for learning? Otherwise, you would probably have used ::std::list from the STL...

I allowed myself to rewrite your list class so you can compare. Hope this helps you...

```cpp
class List
{
public:
    List();
    ~List();

    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node const* getNext() const
        {
            return next;
        }
        Book* getBook() const
        {
            return book;
        }
    private:
        friend class List;
        Node(Book*);
        Node* next;
        Book* book;
    };

    void push_front(Book* book);
    void push_back(Book* book);
    Book* pop_front();
    Book* pop_back();
    Book* getFirst() const;
    Book* getLast() const;

    Node const* getFirstNode() const
    {
        return first;
    }

private:
    Node* first;
    Node* last;
    unsigned int numNodes;
};

List::Node::Node(Book* newBook)
        : next(nullptr), book(newBook)
{
}

List::List()
    : first(nullptr), last(nullptr), numNodes(0)
{
}

List::~List()
{
    while (first)
    {
        Node* tempNode = first;
        first = first->next;
        delete tempNode;
    }
}

void List::push_front(Book* book)
{
    Node* node = new Node(book);
    if (first)
    {
        node->next = first;
        first = node;
    }
    else
    {
        first = last = node;
    }
    ++numNodes;
}

void List::push_back(Book* book)
{
    Node* node = new Node(book);
    if (last)
    {
        last->next = node;
        last = node;
    }
    else
    {
        first = last = node;
    }
    ++numNodes;
}

Book* List::pop_front()
{
    Book* book = nullptr;
    if (first)
    {
        book = first->book;
        Node* tempNode = first;
        first = first->next;
        if (!first)
        {
            last = nullptr;
        }
        delete tempNode;
        --numNodes;
    }
    return book;
}

Book* List::pop_back()
{
    Book* book = nullptr;
    if (last)
    {
        book = last->book;
        Node* tempNode = first;
        if (first == last)
        {
            first = last = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            while(tempNode->next != last)
            {
                tempNode = tempNode->next;
            }
            delete last;
            last = tempNode;
            last->next = 0;
        }
        --numNodes;
    }
    return book;
}

Book* List::getFirst() const
{
    return first ? first->book : nullptr;
}

Book* List::getLast() const
{
    return last ? last->book : nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your crash seems to be related to this part of code:

```
Node* List::pop_front()
{
    if (first != nullptr)
    {
        Node* tempNode = first;
        if (tempNode->getNextNode() == nullptr)
        {
            numNodes--;
            return first;
        }
        if (first == last)
        {
            numNodes--;
            first = nullptr;
            return first;
        }
        first = first->getNextNode();
        numNodes--;
        return tempNode;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Both cases:

```
    if (tempNode->getNextNode() == nullptr)
    {
        numNodes--;
        return first;
    }
    if (first == last)
    {
        numNodes--;
        first = nullptr;
        return first;
    }
```

Seem to serve the purpose of a single-element list (`first == last` and `next == nullptr`). So, the first one should be:

```
    if (tempNode->getNextNode() == nullptr)
    {
        numNodes--;
        first = nullptr;
        return tempNode;
    }
```

Additionally this:

```
Node::Node(Book* newBook)
{
    next = nullptr;
    book = newBook;
}

Node::~Node()
{
    if (next != nullptr)
    {
        delete book;
    }
}
```

is a 100% leak in case of invocation like:

```
new Node(new Book("Test Book 1", "nobody", 1.25))
```

since `next` is still a `nullptr`, and `book` should be owned by `Node`, but isn't. Also, the last element will always leak.